# DataTable moments is not working for sorting Date-Time column?

Tags: php, jquery, datatables, momentjs

Please do not mark as duplicate as I haven't find solutions anywhere.

Following line is not working to sort date and time together in `DataTable`.

[image]

Secondly, I have used following code to make sorting working but it doesn't:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('HH:mm dd/mm/YY');
    //$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm' );
```

and for `DataTable` initialization I have used following code:

```
$('.dataTable').DataTable({
    ordering: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    dom: 'Bftripl',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        //{ "type": "date-euro", targets: 1 }
        //{ "sType": "date-uk", targets: 1 }
    ]
});
```

I have added file : `datetime-moment.js`

None of the code working for sorting out the `date column`, so please anybody help or provide example for it on jsFiddle.

Thanks Friends in advanced:)

For **Anan** your code gives me following output:
after using your updated code but can't pass data as I am feeding data into table using php....

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'HH:mm DD/MM/YYYY' );
$('.dataTable').DataTable({
    ordering: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: true,
    dom: 'Bftripl',
    buttons: [
        'excelHtml5',
        'csvHtml5',
        'pdfHtml5'
    ]
});
```

but unfortunately didn't worked:(
[image]

Comment: Can you please create an `JSFiddle` of your code and add it to your question. It will be helpful to solve your problem.

Comment: your time format about year should 'YYYY'.just like '2016',not '16',you can try in http://live.datatables.net/xedayaxi/1/edit.

Comment: Hi I have tried that as well YYYY but nothing works....:( sorry but I tried almost all the options and that's why I asked if someone create example for me. I looked at your example and you are putting data in your js datatable but can you check if you directly provide your date time into column of html table then it will not work as I try and test your code again but no success.:(

Answer (score 2):

it's because your time format is wrong;look this:

there are my example for it:http://live.datatables.net/xedayaxi/1/edit

according to author,put the data in html ,just look this example:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {

  $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'HH:mm DD/MM/YYYY' );
   
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ordering: true,
    paging: true,
    searching: false,

  });
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>time</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>time</th>

            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>19:46 30/06/2016</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>14:46 29/06/2016</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>19:46 29/07/2018</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>02:16 29/06/2016</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16:46 29/06/2017</td>

            </tr>

          
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi friend thanks for your help but it's not working as you can see the screenshot on my updated answer

Comment: your time format about years should 'YYYY'.just like '2016',not '16'

Comment: Hi I have tried that as well YYYY but nothing works....:( sorry but I tried almost all the options and that's why I asked if someone create example for me. I looked at your example and you are putting data in your js datatable but can you check if you directly provide your date time into column of html table then it will not work as I try and test your code again but no success.:(

Comment: @user2268488 try in my updated answer,it's fine for me ;

Comment: I had a similar issue and the problem was I was setting the time format after creating the datatable